# PowetShell OutputType not defined in some cmdlets

Tags: powershell, scripting, dotnet-cli

Some of the cmdlets that I'm using does not have an OutputType defined. However, when the cmdlet is executed (with parameters) the result has the OutputType.

**Example 1:**

When I execute:

```
Get-Command -Name Get-ADUser | FL *
```

*No OutputType is defined.*

When I execute:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity 'user.name' | Get-Member
```

> TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser

How can I get the TypeName without inputting data.

I'm trying to collate all the Parameter, Verb, Noun and OutputType of all the commands and functions withing a given module (in this case Active Directory).

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: With introspection? No idea. However, [it is in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps#outputs).

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks for the response. I've seen that page. The above was just an example, I'm trying get the output information programmatically, ideally with PowetShell cmdlets, as opposed to using web pages, as there're quite a few cmdlets to go through. This way I could use the same technique for unofficial Modules.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do it programmatically. I believe that the ActiveDirectory module has had fairly minimal updates since it was originally written for the Server 2008 R2 RSAT (mostly to support new AD features). I'm not surprised that it doesn't adhere to modern ideas about module design. You might technically be able to load the assembly and use introspection there, but that's not really a feasible solution, IMO.

Comment: @BaconBits erm... I see!

Comment: @BaconBits however, the Get-ADUser cmdlet was just an example. I'm speaking generally here. I was considering the introspect option using dll decompilers, but, its not preferable. Would by better if it can be done natively on PowerShell.